# Failed to load Xamarin Forms project with .NET Standard 2.0 Lib in Rider

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-standard, rider

TL;DR; **Are Xamarin Forms projects with .NET Standard library 2.0 supported in Rider?**

I created a small Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2017.3 (Windows) using the blank forms app multiplatform wizard. Microsoft dropped the the option to create a PCL recently in the Windows version of VS and provides .NET Standard only. Thus I selected that one.

Now I wanted to try out development on Mac directly using Rider so that I don't have to run a Windows VM (I really like Resharper so I am bound to Windows on my Mac)

When I open this project in Rider on Mac OS, it throws a bunch of errors and it looks like all paths are messed up. Opening it in VS for Mac works fine on the other hand.

I then created a new blank project in VS on Mac with PCL and Rider opens it without complaining. So my Question:
Are Xamarin Forms projects with .NET Standard library 2.0 supported in Rider?

- If they are supported: What am I supposed to do to make it work without breaking the fallback to VS?
- If not: Are there any plans to support it in the near future?

---

Some of my Errors:

- load failed: The imported project "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
- MSBuild targets were not found: Make sure that all SDKs required for projects in this solution are installed, or specify a different MSBuild version in settings.
- Xamarin.Android SDK was not found: Rider was unable to find Xamarin SDK on this machine. Xamarin-based projects will not be loaded. Please install Xamarin SDK or change toolset
- The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly /Users/kay/.nuget/packages/xamarin.forms/2.5.0.122203/build/netstandard1.0/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I think I could start fixing the paths and so on manually, but I am afraid of doing stuff that I don't undersatnd in depth. I used to work with Unity game engine for years but I am new in Xamarin development.

Comment: Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build and change MsBuild from mono. I guess you have all Xamarin targets installed in that msbuild.

Comment: But Rider uses .net core msbuild (without targets) by default for .net standard projects

Comment: @xtmq: GREAT! Selecting _/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/MSBuild.dll_ instead of _/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.3/MSBuild.dll_ did the trick and the project could be built. At first there were some errors when I tried to deploy on Android. After restarting Rider everything was fine. Please put your comment into an answer

Comment: Not a problem =) Moreover we are implementing an improved version of MsBuild autodetection to avoid such issues in the future... will be shipped in 2018.1 or 2018.2 =) See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-7112

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build and change MsBuild from mono. I guess you have all Xamarin targets installed in that msbuild.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is caused by Rider selecting the wrong MSBuild file to use. The .NET Core SDK installs a version of MSBuild that isn't configured to use the Xamarin SDK.

In Rider goto File > Settings > Build, Execution Deployment > Toolset and Build > Use MSBuild version. Select the MSBuild.dll that does **not** reside in the .NET Core SDK path:

[image]

On Windows that will be under Microsoft Visual Studio on MacOS that [appears to be under the Mono.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628318/failed-to-load-xamarin-forms-project-with-net-standard-2-0-lib-in-rider#comment84255722_48628318).

It is important that you fully restart Rider after making this change. After making the change, Rider will try to do a rebuild and fail. Making it seem like your change didn't work. But it appears that the setting doesn't take effect until Rider is fully restarted.

Comment: Selecing msbuild v15 solved the issue. Is it that we cannot use msbuild v16 for Xamarin projects for now?