# Rider 2018.1 iOS simulator not running after build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, rider

I have a Xamarin iOS and Android project with a dotnet standard 2.0 library that is being shared between the two operating systems. When trying to run my iOS project, the project build fine and doesn't give any errors but Rider cannot seem to deploy it to a simulator.
I will give the following error:

[image]

I thought it could be the problem what is described here, but that did not help. When running the project in VS on MacOs, the iOS project also build and runs on a simulator.

[Failed to load Xamarin Forms project with .NET Standard 2.0 Lib in Rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628318/failed-to-load-xamarin-forms-project-with-net-standard-2-0-lib-in-rider)

Can anyone help me trying to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one with this problem, the problem is already reported multiple time in Riders issue tracker:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15544
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15514
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-15419

According to the last issue, it's fixed in Rider 2018.2, which will probably be released pretty soon.