# Xamarin SDK was not found for JetBrains Rider

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, rider

I am hoping to work with Xamarin for a project, primarily to learn a little about cross-platform app development, and would prefer to stick to developing on Linux. This led me to attempt to work with the JetBrains Rider IDE, something that I believed to be fairly well documented, as per these resources:

- [Xamarin.Android on Linux](https://beyondvelocity.blog/2018/11/29/xamarin-android-on-linu/) (in coordination with [its Ubuntu 19.04 update post](https://beyondvelocity.blog/2019/06/02/xamarin-android-on-ubuntu-19-04))
- [Failed to load Xamarin Forms project with .NET Standard 2.0 Lib in Rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48628318/failed-to-load-xamarin-forms-project-with-net-standard-2-0-lib-in-rider)
- [0xFireball's Xamarin.Android on Linux guide](https://github.com/0xFireball/xamarin-android-linux) with associated [Rider/IDE setup](https://github.com/0xFireball/xamarin-android-linux/blob/master/rider-setup.md)

I've been able to install everything just fine, Android Studio and Rider were installed via JetBrains Toolbox (I also tried installing Rider manually, but it made no change), and I am able to create the project and configure the Android settings for the Xamarin project.

This is where my luck ends, since despite trying the various resources I've linked above, including reinstalling mono and dotnet-sdk multiple times, I get this error no matter what I try:

> Xamarin SDK was not found: Rider was unable to find Xamarin SDK on
>   this machine. Xamarin-based projects will not be loaded. Please
>   install Xamarin SDK or change toolset.

I've tried following the instructions both on a manually installed Rider 2019.1.3 (Build #RD-191.7141.460) and Rider 2019.2 EAP (Build #RD-192.5895.291).

I'm fairly new to the world of Xamarin, so I'm not sure where to begin looking. What exactly is the Xamarin SDK (is it just Xamarin.Android?), and what should I be checking my setup for in order for Rider to detect the Xamarin SDK?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what Rider installs via its Environment page, is only the Xamarin Android package. Not the actually Android Studio SDK, which is needed to develop any android apps. You have to download that separately.